# How is this product equal to this permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

This is like the third time the author has brought up something without explanation in this section...

Anyway, in one example right after showing how every permutation can be written as the product of transpositions, the author writes this to demonstrate that the factorizations are not unique:
$$
(2 \space 3)(1 \space 2)(2 \space 5)(1 \space 3)(2 \space 4) = (1 \space 2 \space 4 \space 5) = (1 \space 5)(1 \space 4)(1 \space 2)
$$

Right now, I'm only familiar with factorizations like below, where it is clear where the factors came from.
$$
(1 \space 2 \space 3 \space 4 \space 5) = (1 \space 2)(2 \space 3)(3 \space 4)(4 \space 5)
$$

So what's up with the factors like $(1 \space 4)$ and $(1 \space 5)$ (in the first equation)? I know that you can multiply permutations so that they behave like a composition. So is this the same thing that's happening here? I'm confused about how the products on the sides are equal to the permutation in the middle, so I would appreciate it if someone would show me step-by-step on how to deduce that the products are indeed equal.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven woops i mistyped it, fixed now.

Comment: I typically check compositions of permutations by where the elements get mapped to. For example we want to know where $1$ gets mapped to. The first factor $(24)$ fixes $1$. The second factor $(13)$ maps $1$ to $3$. The third and fourth factor fix $3$ and the last factor maps $3$ to $2$. Hence the composition maps $1$ to $2$, which is also what the middle thing does. Now you can check where $2$ gets mapped to and so on.

Comment: Another example, for $3$ we have $$ 3\mapsto 3 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 3.$$ That means $3$ is fixed under the composition and likewise for the middle expression.

Comment: Why? It is the same process. We have $$4\mapsto 4 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 5.$$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think it goes like this: $$4 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 2$$

Comment: Where does $1$ get mapped to under $(15)$?

Comment: You are doing composition in the wrong order. If you have functions $f\circ g$, then you first apply $g$ and then $f$. Same for permutations (as they are just bijective functions).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Right, so if $(12)$ is the right-most factor, why doesn't it go first in this case?

Comment: It does.... it fixes $4$, thus I wrote $4\mapsto 4$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ohhh I get it now! For some reason instead of carrying the result over to left factor, I was starting all over again (i need some sleep)! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! I definitely need some sleep too, but first I treat myself to some cheesecake :)